# LaTex function \renewbibmacro*{} does not output APA 7th edition citations and bibliographies

Tags: reference, pdflatex

I have the following LaTex code for citations with APA 7th edition style:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber, citestyle=bwl-FU]{biblatex}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}%to fit the bibliography to the margins 
\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
\makeatletter 
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish} {\setcounter{smartand}{1}% or some other value 
    \let\lbx@finallistdelim=\lbx@es@smartand \let\lbx@finalnamedelim=\lbx@es@smartand} 
% #1 = last name
% #2 = first name
% #3 = first name (initials)
% #4 = name prefix, a.k.a. 'von part'
% #5 = name affix, a.k.a. 'junior part'
\renewbibmacro*{name:delim:apa:family-given}[1]{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
            or
            test \ifmorenames
        }
        {\printdelim{multinamedelim}}
        {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}} 
\makeatother
\bibliography{parts/bibliography.bib}
```

The code to add the bibliography to the PDF file is:

```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHICAL REFERENCES}%bibliography in biblatex
  \printbibliography[title={\LARGE \textcolor{tit2}{BIBLIOGRAPHICAL REFERENCES}}]%show the bibliography in PDF
```

**Problem with PDF file:** the output in the PDF file are citations of the LaTex code that was used and the bibliography does not appear.

**Problem indicated in the Winshell console:** main.tex(1): Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'name:delim:apa:family-given' undefined.

**Editor:** Winshell with pdfLaTex.

*How do I solve the above problems so that the PDF file of the document shows the citations with the APA 7th edition and the bibliography of the citations used? Thank you very much for your help*

**General structure for generating the PDF file of the document:** the ... indicates that there is more code

1. main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[] %with arguments
...
\input{parts/package}
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}...
\renewcommand{}...
\include{}...
%bibliography
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHICAL REFERENCES}...%indicated at the beginning of the question
...
\end{document}
```

2. Folders:

```
parts/Introduction.tex
parts/Chapter1.tex
parts/bibliography.bib
...
parts/packages_work.tex
```

packages_work.tex:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
...
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber, citestyle=bwl-FU]{biblatex}...%indicated at the beginning of the question
```